# Integration Testing In Django Involving Reverse Lambda Call

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to test a django application which involves AWS lambda talking back to the django server. Mock testing does not help catching the bug, so I need the original lambda function to be part of the test.
The Django TestCase creates a temporary database for testing apart from the production database, which is good. However, when lambda function calls back to the server, it is outside of the context of the TestCase and therefore it refers to the production database instead of the test database and the test fails to complete.
Is there any way to override the django settings **globally** to use the test database during the integration test?

I tried to override the settings of the TestCase, but it does not apply globally, rather it is just for the TestCase.